# Ordered vs Unordered POV is giving different probabilities: hand is void in at least one suit

Tags: probability

> A card player is dealt a 13 card hand from a well-shuffled, standard
> deck of cards. What is the probability that the hand is void in at
> least one suit (“void in a suit” means having no cards of that suit)?

Why can't the answer be $4(3/4)^{13} - 6(1/2^{13}) + 4/4^{13}$

Why does this produce an answer that isn't equivalent to the one produced by the unordered perspective? In other words, why can't we view $(3/4)^{13}$ as equal to $\binom{39}{13}/\binom{52}{13}$?

Comment: $(\frac{3} {4})^{13}$ is drawing **with** replacement, $\Large\frac{\binom{39}{13}}{\binom{52}{13}}$ is **without** replacement

Answer (score 1):

Without delving too deeply into your posting, I will answer the specific question that you posed.  If you have further questions, leave a comment following my answer, and I will edit my answer in response.

Suppose that you were going to receive $(13)$ cards, from a $(52)$ card deck.  What is the probability that none of the cards are **SPADES**?

**IF** the drawing is with replacement, where you are given a card, the card is placed back in the deck, you are given another card (and so forth, $13$ times), then the probability that none of the cards is a SPADE is

$$\left[\frac{39}{52}\right]^{13} = \left[\frac{3}{4}\right]^{13}.$$

**However**, **much** more usual in such a scenario, is that the distribution of the $(13)$ cards is done without replacement.

This means, for example, that while the probability that the first card drawn is **NOT A SPADE** is in fact

$$\frac{39}{52}$$

then, assuming that your first card is not a spade, the probability that the 2nd card is **ALSO NOT A SPADE** is

$$\frac{38}{51} \neq \frac{39}{52}.$$

This is because, once you receive a non-spade, when the  sampling is done without replacement, there are $(51)$ cards left in the deck, of which only $38$ of the cards are non-spades.

When sampling without replacement, overall, the probability of drawing $(13)$ cards, none of which is a spade is

$$\frac{39 \times 38 \times \cdots \times 27}{52 \times 51 \times \cdots \times 40}$$

$$= \frac{\binom{39}{13}}{\binom{52}{13}}.$$